# Downloading pdf file doesn't work in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to download a pdf file from url but I encountered error :

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 443
}
```

and here is my code:

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");


const url = #hidden#

const optionsStart = {
    uri: url,
    method: 'GET',
    encoding: null,
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'applcation/pdf'
    }
}


const req = https.get(optionsStart, function(res){
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream("Testingpdf123.pdf");
    res.pipe(fileStream);

    fileStream.on("error", function(err){
        console.log("Error writing to the stream.");
        console.log(err);
    });

    fileStream.on("finish", () => {  
        fileStream.close();
        console.log("Done!");
    });

});
```

I tried replacing optionsStart to just url but the file is blank. What's wrong with my code?

UPDATE:

I remove the method: 'GET' in optionsStart it creates a pdf file but empty then I check what's inside the file it says

```
<meta name="heading" content="Access Denied" />
```

Comment: I wonder what `ECONNREFUSED` does mean..... 

Comment: The error suggests that the URL starts with `https://127.0.0.1/`, but there's no server running there.

Comment: Is there any server running at 127.0.0.1 ? The error says there isn't

Comment: Typo: `applcation` should be `application`

Comment: @tevemadar change to application but still the content of pdf says <meta name="heading" content="Access Denied" />

Answer (score 0):

You need to change yow port 443 is an encrypted or secure port you need to provide them ssl certificates  and stuff also use the http module instead of the https module.... for development on yow prod app the story is different